# How we can use H.323 phone over TLS on avaya?

Tags: ssl, voip, tls1.2, avaya, h.323

I found on the internet that we can edit 46xxsettings.txt file but I can't find this file on the server.

Answer (score 1):

46xxsettings.txt file is downloaded from the TFTP server during phone bootup.

You can use the DHCP option-176/242 for specifying the TFP server's address in the DHCP server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the information , it would be more helpful if you can elaborate your answer.